# How to automate actions in certain apps?

Tags: automation

I have a Note 5 running Android 7.0. I use an app to get scheduled for work. Is there any app that could automate my scheduling in the app? Getting schedule is very hard if I do it manually by updating the screen manually for 30 minutes at least. I checked Automate and MacroDroid but could not find any actions that would control third party apps. If no app is available, is there examples of a Java code to see how controlling on Android works. I could modify the code for my use case. Thanks! [image: Update button on bottom]

Comment: You might want to explain where the schedule is coming from (csv file, different app), as automated 'manual' re-entry is only slightly better than physically typing. Also mention if you are using a cloud calendar provider (Google Calendar/Microsoft Outlook, etc.)

Comment: Hi. This is an app as you can see on the screenshot. When I click that 'update schedule' button, it shows hours with + sign. If there is no + sign, it means that hour is scheduled for someone else. It does not download any file nor uses calendar. It has only internet connection. The only way I can think of would be emitating my clicking of buttons with a script or code.

Comment: You can look into AutoInput. https://lifehacker.com/autoinput-for-tasker-automates-any-ui-interaction-for-t-1646593876 I have not tried it but read a lot that it can automate UI interaction.

Comment: Automate has two Interact blocks for simulating touch actions within other apps. If the other app doesn't support automation, that the only way.

Comment: Firelord and ballzak, thanks! That was the solution!

Answer (score 1):

By default regular Apps can't control other apps.

There are two exceptions:

1. If the app is a system app (signed with the same cryptographic key that was used to sign the OS itself)
2. An app can request access to the "accessibility services". Using this service  an app can interact with other apps.

Note that Google is currently (mid 2018) restricting the accessibility service usage. Only apps that use it for legitimate purposes are allowed (helping disabled people to use an Android phone. As you can imagine controlling third party apps is not a legitimate purpose for Google's perspective.

Comment: So, then, is there a possibility to create a script or code that would emulate touching the screen as if it was human input but automated?

Comment: Tasker can do that

Comment: Automate can do that, use the Interact blocks.